# How to set default context-param values for ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets, applicationcontext

How to set default `boolean` values with `ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`? For example, I want property to have `false` value if it is not set as `<context-param>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always define a default value for every place where the property configurere "inject" some value.

The default synax is `${propertyName:default}`

So for example:

```
${myContextParam:false}
```